# Como deixar o meu banco no postgres sempre ordenado?

Tags: postgresql

Estou fazendo um sistema de busca de paginas no qual irei sempre fazer a sequinte consulta no banco:

```
'SELECT title FROM pages ORDER BY title ASC OFFSET' +iniciaL + 'FETCH FIRST 32 ROWS ONLY'
```

Escolho um OFFSET inicial e sempre pego os proximos 32. Porém acho que essa ordenação sempre irá custar algum processamento. Queria saber se já existe algum comando no postgres que irá deixar minha tabela `pages` sempre ordenada e assim que eu realizar esta consulta: `'SELECT title FROM pages ASC OFFSET' +iniciaL + 'FETCH FIRST 32 ROWS ONLY'` eu tenha 100% de garantia que os resultados já estejam ordenados(se eu caso nao deu INSERT é claro).

É eficiente isso sabendo que minhas inserções só acontecem uma vez ao dia, 12:00? ou deixo assim mesmo?

(A tabela pages irá possuir cerca de 5.5milhoẽs de linhas)

Comment: acho que ele quis dizer rows

Comment: mals é rows mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabendo que seu update so acontece uma vez no dia eu fortemente recomendo a criacao de uma [Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rules-materializedviews.html) vc pode salvar de forma ordenada e fazer o refresh diario depois do update

exemplo da propria documentacao:

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sales_summary AS
  SELECT
      seller_no,
      invoice_date,
      sum(invoice_amt)::numeric(13,2) as sales_amt
    FROM invoice
    WHERE invoice_date < CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY
      seller_no,
      invoice_date
    ORDER BY
      seller_no,
      invoice_date;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sales_summary_seller
  ON sales_summary (seller_no, invoice_date);
```